# IPhonesdk Orientation Issue

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have two views, on first view i have multiple buttons, i wanted that view to be landscape right so i put this code :

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
     return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

it works fine as my application starts in landscape right mode. the buttons on this view pushes user to second view which i wanted to be a portrait mode. so i put that code in second view but its not working as i wanted.

```
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
         return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
    }
```

its showing my the orientation which i had on previous view. should i have to put something on viewdidload to make it works? please help. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit a hack, but here it is. In the `-(void)viewDidLoad` of the viewController that you want to force portrait for do the following:

```
UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:NO];
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
[viewController release];
```

This basically forces portrait, by presenting a controller (which only supports portrait by default).

Answer (score 0):

You should use one orientation for all view controllers. Otherwise you may have some problems. For example in your case imagine that the user has switched to the second view and has changed the orientation to *UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait*. Now he returns to the first screen and all buttons are on the wrong positions! Actually the problem is that the orientation will not change to *UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight* back as you expect. It happens because *shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation* is not called after *viewWillAppear* is triggered. So you have to code some dirty hacks to force orientation change. It is not a good solution.

By the way, how do you change your controllers? If you are using *addSubview*, then your second controller's *shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation* will not be triggered at all. When using addSubview you should handle it by yourself.